# Cake PHP 3 - template generate div with template that i can't remove

Tags: php, templates, cakephp

Just a little problem ! In my document i return an input like this

```
 return parent::input($fieldName, [ 
    'div'=> false, 
    'label' => [
          'class' => ' control-label col-md-'.$this->getLeft().' '
    ],
    'templates' => [
        'formGroup' => '{{label}} <div class="form-group col-md-'.$this->getRight().'"> {{input}} </div>'
    ], 
    'class' => 'form-control' 
]);
```

In my document i got something like that

```
<div class="input text required">
    <label class"control-label col-md-3" for="title">Title</label>
        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required="required" maxlength="50" id="title" value="Article premier de la constitution">
        </div>
</div>
```

In really don't want that first div ! Prefer something like that :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class"control-label col-md-3" for="title">Title</label>
        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required="required" maxlength="50" id="title" value="Article premier de la constitution">
        </div>
</div>
```

I try to understand templates... So how can i call my template to have a good render ? Or what should i do with the "div=>false" of my input ?

Comment: what do you mean by "what should i do with the "div=>false" of my input ?" ?. 'div'=>'false' will not render input div.

Comment: There's a problem with that option. Div => false render the div. Like it's everytime to true state ! I searched others topic and others meet the same problem. That's why i use the CakePHP3 templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should edit the Default config for the helper.

Go to: 
**vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php**

Find and copy all templates structures what you can edit:

```
protected $_defaultConfig = [
    ...
    'templates' => [
        'inputContainer' => '<div class="input {{type}}{{required}}">{{content}}</div>',
        ...
    ]
];
```

Go and create file **config/app_form.php**

Open **app_form.php** paste structure edit and make our own template

```
<?php 

return [
   'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group">{{content}}</div>'

];
```

Now go to **View/AppView.php** and edit initialize function

```
 public function initialize()
    {
        $this -> loadHelper('Form', [
            'templates' => 'app_form' //Name of file created in previous step
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I progress little by little. Now i just shut down the div that i don't want.

Answer to delete the div :

```
return parent::input($fieldName, ['label' => ['class' => ' control-label col-md-'.$this->getLeft().' '],
                                  'templates' => ['inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group">{{content}}</div>'], 'class' => 'form-control col-md-9' ]);

}
```

- New problem : How can i parse the content that i call ? Because
  before i got '{{label}}' and '{{input}}' that made me abble to put
  the div i want between those two... Can someone say me how can I explode this
  {{content}} in two parts ?